# Wrong use of memset?

Tags: c++

Can someone please explain what is wrong here:

```
class test
{
public:
    char char_arr[100];
};

int main()
{
    test **tq = (test**)calloc(10, sizeof(test*));
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        tq[i] = (test*)calloc(10,  sizeof(test));

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        memset(tq, 0, sizeof(tq[0][0])*100);

    return 0;
}
```

The code above produces random crashes. The errors are: "memory could not be written", "memory could not be read", "stack is corrupted"

Comment: You need to explain what you need at least. And also add the error that you are having.

Comment: You seem to be mainly simply forgetting to use `tq[i]` in your second loop, instead of `tq`. But that aside, multiplying by 100 seems suspicious.

Comment: `calloc` zeroes the memory allocated. why `memset` again?

Comment: You have an array of pointers, not an array of arrays.

Comment: `sizeof` doesn't do what you think it does!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
test **tq = (test**)calloc(10, sizeof(test*));

...

for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    memset(tq, 0, sizeof(tq[0][0])*100);
```

When you allocate `tq`, you ask for `10 * sizeof(test*)` bytes. But when you call `memset`, you ask it to set `sizeof(tq[0][0]*100)` bytes. You are definitely writing to more bytes then you allocated. Perhaps you meant:

```
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    memset(tq[i], 0, 10 * sizeof(test));
```

This makes sense because:

```
    tq[i] = (test*)calloc(10,  sizeof(test));
```

When you allocated `tq[i]`, you allocated `10 * sizeof(test)` bytes.

Comment: @Luka No. Since `tq` is a `test**`, `tq[0]` is a `test*`, so `sizeof(tq[0])` is `sizeof(test*)`.

Comment: Yes. That's correct. For the sake of all that is holy, don't do this and use sane C++ types like std::vector or std::array.

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing this for a 2D array:

```
char x[10][10];
```

This is a 2D array, which holds 100 contiguous `char`s.

But you have allocated a bunch of pointers, then pointed them to separate arrays of 10 chars each. The result is not contiguous; you cannot access it in the way you have.

Comment: Aha, I see. So, when I call 10 times calloc, those 10 memory location are not continues and can be random, correct?

Comment: Correct; you allocated a bunch of pointers; you need to follow them as they are independent of each other.